# Artifactory Docker port configuration F5

Tags: docker, artifactory, f5, jfrog-container-registry, irule

We are trying to configure docker port method configuration in F5 and we added below Irule and we are not able to login into docker repo

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
if { [HTTP::uri] starts_with "/v2/"} {
  set ARTI_PROTO http
  set ARTI_PORT 3000
  set ARTI_HOST test.artifactory.com (shoud this be nice URL or server name/IP where application is hosted)
    HTTP::uri /artifactory/api/docker/testdocker[HTTP::uri]
    HTTP::header insert X-Forwarded-Proto $ARTI_PROTO
    HTTP::header insert X-Forwarded-Port $ARTI_PORT
    HTTP::header insert Host $ARTI_HOST:$ARTI_PORT  -- is this value of host and one in below line  should be same or different ?
    HTTP::header insert X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $ARTI_PROTO://$ARTI_HOST:$ARTI_PORT/artifactory
}
}
```

we are getting below error

Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://test.artifactory.com:3000/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request

Is there something that we are doing wrong with irule configuration could somebody help us in mapping correct configuration

Comment: Which version of artifactory are you using? In my artifactory The only http setting for reverse proxy, I get apache/nginx/embedded tomcat

Comment: We are using the artifactory version 6.13.3

Comment: And also we dont see option for F5 in http setting So we selected option as embedded tomcat Is it correct to select Embedded tomcat ? will that route to F5 and how will artifactory understands its routing via F5?